# Form controls displaced when installed on another computer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

*I know there will be folks who will vote this question down or ask for close. But if there is any kind of information or code I can provide you to know more about my program I will let you know. So please keep reading and see if you have had a similar problem.*

I am running a `Win7` 64bit with .Net Framework ver 4.5.

I have created a `Winform` application. And to create my form elements I have taken advantage of a library called [Metroframework](http://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/) that gives the program a metro look and feel. It contains some standard controls and as well as user controls that inherit from the original `Form` class. This is the opening view of my program.

[image]

However, for some strange reason, when I came to install my program on two other computers (one running `Win7` and the other `Win8`), I noticed that some of my form elements have changed their location and some have just disappeared or just have been displaced. This has frightened me knowing the amount of time I have spent to put this elements in place.

Everything looks fine on my own computer both in dev environment and after building my application in release version. At first I thought this is a screen resolution problem on the other two devices, but that was not the case either. And even if it was, why should this happen?

Can anyone please help me solve this problem? I will share any part of my code you need. But I really have no idea where the source of this problem is!

Comment: Have you checked the Form.AutoScaleMode? Sometimes it helps to go from Dpi or Font to None..

Comment: @TaW I will test and come back to you on that.

Comment: @TaW your answer was correct. you can post it as the right answer if you want. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main influence on the layout variations on different machines is the`Form.AutoScaleMode`property.

In theory the default setting should work fine but I found that sometimes it is best to switch it off completely, that is going from `Dpi` or `Font` to `None`..

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains a little about the intended effect.

BTW: The is also a `ContainerControl.AutoScaleMode` property, so you could choose different modes for some parts of your forms as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The AutoScaleMode property specifies the current automatic scaling
>   mode of this control. Scaling by Font is useful if you want to have a
>   control or form stretch or shrink according to the size of the fonts
>   in the operating system, and should be used when the absolute size of
>   the control or form does not matter. Scaling by Dpi is useful when you
>   want to size a control or form relative to the screen. For example,
>   you may want to use dots per inch (DPI) scaling on a control
>   displaying a chart or other graphic so that it always occupies a
>   certain percentage of the screen.

To remain true to the pixel-precise layout use:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
```

The last value in the `AutoScaleMode` enumeration is `Inherited` which most often would be chosen for nested containers.

Update: The choice of `ContainerControls`is rather limited:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form
System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid
System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContainer
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanel
System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

Maybe the most useful is the `UserControl`. Note that it doesn't expose the `AutoScale` property in its instances but only in the class definition. Also note that you can't add controls to an instance in the desiger, but you could assemble them in maybe a `Panel` and then set a `UserControl` (with `AutoScale=Font`) to be the Panel's Parent.. You'll need to allow for some extra space in any case, though..